# Is Chromium still under consideration for Unity?

Tags: unity, chromium

During uds-m there were discussions to include Chromium as the default browser for the - back then - netbook edition. However, it was opted to stay with Firefox.

Have there been further discussions at uds-n about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox (4) was chosen at the recent Ubuntu Developer Summit to be the default for 11.04 Unity Desktop and Netbook Editions.

One of Chromium's biggest drawbacks is working out how to integrate its six weekly release cycle into Ubuntu's six monthly schedule.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! But is it still considered for future releases, or will Ubuntu definitely stay with Firefox? Note that I did not particularly ask about 11.04 but more in general ;)

Comment: if you follow the blogs (developer and others) you'd know that FF4 is improving by leaps and bounds. Chromium is not stable enough, so please...

Comment: @Ingo I'm sure it will be reviewed again in six months. At the moment the release cycle issue is preventing a *better* discussion about which we want in Ubuntu. However I'm sure that will get sorted out - and of course considering the pace of development, Chromium will be very different in six months time compared to how it is now!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Firefox 4 would be the default browser in the 11.04

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. [Ubuntu Developer Summit (uds-1305) will start tomorrow](http://uds.ubuntu.com/).

> [Chromium as default browser](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1305/meeting/21788/foundations-1305-chromium-default-browser/http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1305/meeting/21788/foundations-1305-chromium-default-browser/)
>
> 2013-05-16 16:05..17:00 in Client 1
>
> Chromium has matured to being as good or better than Firefox. It will be the foundation of a lot of Ubuntu Touch code and webapps code. We should consider using Chromium as the default browser in Ubuntu.

---

> 2013-08-12
>
> [Firefox is to remain the default browser](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/firefox-to-remain-default-browser-in-ubuntu-13-10) in Ubuntu 13.10, Ubuntu developers have today confirmed.

but ...

> I do want to consider Chromium by default for 14.04 once the above is no longer an issue. I sincerely believe Chromium is the better experience for general users and should be strongly considered for our next LTS.

Answer (score -2):

Check this url:

Natty’s default app selection

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/nattys-default-apps-stay-familiar/

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I was not asking about the particular release 11.04, but more general consideration.

Comment: For the time being Firefox will stay default....